# Django - static folder mapping in urls.py

Tags: python, django

I have following files structure in my django app

```
|-myapp
|---static
|-----adminapp
|-----clientapp
|-----commonapp
|-----css
|-----fonts
|-----js
|---templates
|-----administration
|-------index.html
|-----client
|-------index.html
```

It's because I want to build two angular apps, one for users (`static/clientapp`) and one for admin (`static/adminapp`).

`templates/administration/index.html` and `templates/client/index.html` are similar and contains code like:

```
<head>
    <script src="static/js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="static/adminapp/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="adminapp"></body>
```

Links to my admin and client apps should be:

```
http://example.com/administration/  
http://example.com/client/
```

The question is what entry should I add to `urls.py` to let both angular apps access to the same `static` folder.

It must by something like:

```
url(r'^administration/static/$', STATIC_ROOT),
url(r'^client/static/$', STATIC_ROOT)
```

but I'm django newbie and I don't know how to define it correctly.

Comment: I don't understand your question. It's very unusual to use django's url router for static files. The development server just takes a root folder and then serves static content according to the directory structure there. It's not clear to me what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

In production you should not let Django handle the static files, so it should be in your nginx/appache config to set the correct paths for `administation/static/` and `client/static/`.

For dev purposes, you could add something like this:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^administation/static/(?P<path>.*)$', ' django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.ADMIN_STATIC_ROOT}),
        url(r'^client/static/(?P<path>.*)$', ' django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.CLIENT_STATIC_ROOT}),
   ]
```

Then you only have to define `ADMIN_STATIC_ROOT` and `CLIENT_STATIC_ROOT` in your settings.

Comment: @akn , or for any one who might be interested - For some context on why people say "you should not let Django handle static files" or "It's very unusual to use django's url router for static files" - the [Django docs on built-in views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/views/#serving-files-in-development) suggest "This view is not hardened for production use and should be used only as a development aid; you should serve these files in production using a real front-end web server"

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use `/` in urls to static resources.

e.g.

```
<script src="/static/js/angular.js"></script>
```

Then app base url has no matter.